# NUMA node tensorflow negative one value

Tags: tensorflow, numa

I built tensorflow from sources using bazel and when I finally open a session, I get the following warning:

```
2017-05-07 15:45:40.816127: I 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful 
NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be 
at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this? I don't want to just hide the warning, but somehow solve it such that NUMA node is zero.

I am using Lenovo Y50-70 on Nvidia-381 graphics driver.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've seen this warning before, it's likely this is due to missing functionality in TF itself

Comment: So can we do anything about it?

Comment: nope, need to wait for TensorFlow to start supporting NUMA